# DataTables warning: table id=crudTable - Ajax error

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, laravel-8

Please see my problem below ,  I am using laravel 8 and jquery datatables, when i just get error like in title. Maybe someone can help me?

```
<script>
        var datatable = $('#crudTable').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ordering: true,
            ajax: {
                url: '{!! url()->current() !!}',
            },
            columns: [
                {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
                {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
                {data: 'photo', name: 'photo'},
                {data: 'slug', name: 'slug'},
                {
                    data: 'action',
                    name: 'action',
                    orderable: false,
                    searcable: false,
                    width: '15%'
                },
            ]
        })
    </script>
```

How can I solve this problem?? Please help me... I'm looking for a solution, all day long!!

Answer (score 0):

change your datatable id and it will work!